# Equalities for trace with symbols

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

Mathematica does not seem to know basic rules for computation with trace when one uses symbols; e.g.

```
FullSimplify[Tr[A.B] == Tr[B.A]]
```

gives as output

```
Tr[A.B] == Tr[B.A]
```

and

```
FullSimplify[Tr[A.B + G.F] == (Tr[A.B] + Tr[G.F])]
```

gives

```
Tr[A.B] + Tr[G.F] == Tr[A.B + G.F]
```

Is it possible to teach Mathematica these rules and force it to use them to simplify expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your own trace:

```
ClearAll[TR] ;
TR /: Equal[TR[Dot[A_, B_]], TR[Dot[B_, A_]]] := True ;
TR[Dot[A_, B_] + Dot[C_, D_]] := TR[Dot[A, B]] + TR[Dot[C, D]] ;
```

Then:

```
FullSimplify[Tr[A . B] == Tr[B . A] /. Tr -> TR]
FullSimplify[Tr[A . B + G . F] == (Tr[A . B] + Tr[G . F]) /. Tr -> TR]
(* True *)
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

One idea is to use the ["ToTensor"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ToTensor) [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) to convert the traces into [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) objects:

```
ResourceFunction["ToTensor"][
    Tr[A . B],
    Assumptions -> (A|B) ∈ Matrices[{d,d}]
]
ResourceFunction["ToTensor"][
    Tr[B . A],
    Assumptions -> (A|B) ∈ Matrices[{d,d}]
]
```

> TensorContract[A [TensorProduct] B, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}]

> TensorContract[A [TensorProduct] B, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}]

Or:

```
ResourceFunction["ToTensor"][
    Tr[A . B] == Tr[B . A],
    Assumptions -> (A|B) ∈ Matrices[{d,d}]
]
```

> True

Similarly:

```
ResourceFunction["ToTensor"][
    Tr[A . B] + Tr[G . F] == Tr[A . B + G . F],
    Assumptions -> (A|B|F|G) ∈ Matrices[{d,d}]
]
```

> True

Another possibility is to use the ["FromTensor"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FromTensor) and ["ToTensor"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ToTensor) resource functions to canonicalize an object:

```
$Assumptions = (A|B) ∈ Matrices[{d,d}];
ResourceFunction["FromTensor"] @ ResourceFunction["ToTensor"][Tr[B . A]]
ResourceFunction["FromTensor"] @ ResourceFunction["ToTensor"][Tr[A . B]]
```

> Tr[B . A]

> Tr[B . A]

and:

```
$Assumptions = (A|B|F|G) ∈ Matrices[{d,d}];
ResourceFunction["FromTensor"] @ ResourceFunction["ToTensor"][Tr[A . B+G . F]]
```

> Tr[B . A] + Tr[G . F]

Answer (score 5):

You can use Distribute:

```
Distribute[Tr[A . B + G . F]] === Tr[A . B] + Tr[G . F]
(*True*)
```